# Extracting precise data required from Viewmodel to send to view with 3 models present?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 models (shortened):

Course model:

```
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Meta { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string titleabbrev { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<course_section> course_sections { get; set; }
```

Course section model:

```
[Key]
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Course_page")]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Colour_class { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public virtual Course_page Course_page { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<course_subsection> course_subsections { get; set; }
```

Course subsection model:

```
[Key]
    public int SubSectionID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("course_section")]
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Icon_class { get; set; }
    public string Colour_class { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Titleabbrev { get; set; }
    public string Pagecontent { get; set; }

    public virtual course_section course_section { get; set; }
```

They are combined in the viewmodel:

```
public class CourseViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Course_page> Course_page { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<course_section> Course_section { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<course_subsection> Course_subsection { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I have 3 foreach loops designed to print out onto the page the sections and relevant subsections in order.

In my controller for the view I have the following:

```
public ActionResult Course_page(string courseabbrev)
    {


        var viewModel = new CourseViewModel();
        viewModel.Course_page = db.Course_page
        .Where(i => i.titleabbrev == courseabbrev)
        .Include(i => i.course_sections.Select(c => c.course_subsections));


       viewModel.Course_section = viewModel.Course_page.Where(i => i.titleabbrev == courseabbrev)
            .Single().course_sections
            .OrderBy(i => i.Order);

        //viewModel.Course_subsection = db.course_subsection.ToList()
        //    .OrderBy(i => i.Order);

        viewModel.Course_subsection = viewModel.Course_section.First().course_subsections;


        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I'm trying to send to the view, only the sections and subsections for the course selected when loading the page.  Currently I can get the page to appear how I would like by using the line commented out above:

```
viewModel.Course_subsection = db.course_subsection.ToList()
           .OrderBy(i => i.Order);
```

Then in my view I use an if statement within the 3rd foreach loop to to match the sectionID in viewModel.Course_section with the sectionID in viewModel.Course_subsection, so that it prints out only the relevant subsections for that section.

This works but seems to be overkill as I am sending a list of all subsections to the page.

The other alternative that can be seen in the controller is:

```
 viewModel.Course_subsection = viewModel.Course_section.First().course_subsections;
```

This will only send back the first group of course_subsections because of course I am using First().

My question is what is the best way to send this data to the view?  Is there a way I can only send the subsections I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
viewModel.Course_subsection = viewModel.Course_section
                                       .SelectMany(c => c.course_subsections);
```